# how to correct the result for the code below with sys.argv

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've tried this on python 2.7

```
import sys

a = int (sys.argv [1])
b = int (sys.argv [2])

c = a + b
```

---

The result is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\gispy\Sample_scripts\ch02\add_version2.py", line 8, in <module>
     a = int (sys.argv [1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Your code shows you trying to access index positions 1 and 2, but your Traceback is showing 3. How are you calling this script exactly? And why is your Traceback not reflective of the code you are showing?

Comment: in fact the correct text is the folowing                                                  **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\gispy\Sample_scripts\ch02\add_version2.py", line 8, in <module>
    a = int (sys.argv [1])
IndexError: list index out of range**

Comment: You're still not providing how you are actually calling it. Also, make sure you update your question and add all proper relevant updates there. Adding it in the comments is not helpful. You need a more complete example of your problem to help clarify what is going on. Read how to put together a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was calling the code in a inappropriate software